# Is there a way of returning a column value based on data in an array in Google sheets?

Tags: arrays

Below is an image of my source data. I am using Google Sheets. It has student names in Column A, and the groups that they have signed up for in the rest of the table:

[image: Below is an image of my source data. It has student names in Column A, and the groups that they have signed up for in the rest of the table]

I am trying to look for all instances of each group in the array, and then return all of the names linked to that group. Please refer to the image below for what I'm after.

Final table:

[image: Final table]

I have used the FILTER function to do something similar with just a column, but am stumped to apply the same logic to an array.

Comment: Are you using pencil and paper or is your question related to some software, database or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Assuming your data is on a tab called 'data', like this:

[image]

I've created another tab for the solution.

On the solution tab, you can paste the following formula into cell A1 to dynamically get all of your Groups (as headings):

`=arrayformula(transpose(query(unique(flatten(data!B:F)),"where Col1 is not null",0)))`

[image]

It assumes data on the data tab is in columns B to F (`data!B:F`)). You can extend `F` to whatever it needs to be.

Then we have the `query` on the solution tab, in cell A2:

`=query({data!$B:$B,data!$A:$A;data!$C:$C,data!$A:$A;data!$D:$D,data!$A:$A;data!$E:$E,data!$A:$A;data!$F:$F,data!$A:$A},"select Col2 where Col1 matches '"&A$1&"' order by Col1,Col2",0)`

The `query` range is in `{}`. Note the `,` and the `;` within the range.

`,` is a new row, `;` is a return. The range is column B with column A to the right, then a return and column C with column A to the right, then a return and column D with column A to the right, etc. If you need to extend the column range, add `;data!$N:$N,data!$A:$A` within the right `}` where 'N' is the next column letter.

There is a `query` on this dataset that selects `Col2` from the dataset (Names), where `Col1` matches the value in cell A1 (Group 1).

[image]

You can drag this formula to the right, from cell A2 to B2, to C2, to D2 etc. The only thing that changes whilst dragging is `where Col1 matches '"&A$1&"'` changes to `where Col1 matches '"&B$1&"'` to `where Col1 matches '"&C$1&"'` etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aresvik, I'll give it a go!

Comment: I've updated the original post with a simpler query.

Comment: Thanks Aresvik for you help. I've had a few days now learning more about QUERY and it has made my work much more efficient.

Comment: I've added another update. If you like any of the answers, then please accept them. It rewards the work put in and also helps others who are looking for similar solutions  :-)